# iOS - images stretched in stack-view

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout, uistackview

Here is my status I created stack-view with two sub views --> vertical and horizontal stack-view

the horizontal view contains 3 button

check image below

[image]

my issue when I set background to button its stretched as appear in image

[image]

my tries to fix this issue ,

1-  set view mode to aspect-fit

2- increase spacing between button

3- set fixed width and height to one of buttons as all obey

but unfortunately all my tries doesn't work , any one could guide me to fix my issue thanks

Comment: You should set the view mode of your `UIImageView`s to `Center` not `Aspect fit`.

Comment: thank you for answer , but this give strange behavior , as my stack-view horizontal

Comment: @Majster solution worked for my vertical stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try to use `SetImage` Instead of `BackgroundImage`that will fix the issue else use the proper image with proper size that you want to implement based on your requrement. see the following difference between `setImage` and `SetBackgroundImage`

[image]

Here you need to change your image size with your stack view's button image that will be fix your issue and for using stack view following is a good link: https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views

Comment: thank you for answer , but I think the reason of this stretch my stack-view I do as you suggest but its the same

Comment: your image size is not proper first create an image with proper size

Comment: do you sugguest size , I need image 24*24 is this proper size

Comment: see your image size and your stack view's button size you need this size image

Comment: thanks mate this fix my issue please update your answer to accept it , but I have small question how to make view in middle as first image in the left view , second one in middle and third one in the right . thanks